# Java regexp to force case in search

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a PDF reader, iAnnotate, that allows one to search a document using `java.util.regex.Pattern` regexps.  Unfortunately, iAnnotate ignores case in all searches.  This happens even if you use an expression like `[A]` (it also finds "a"), and even if you specify the character in unicode (`\u0041` means "A", but iAnnotate also finds "a").

Java regexps are not designed to ignore case by default, and I don't see any way to use them to override ignore-case behavior in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but maybe there's something I'm not thinking of.

Any suggestions for possible regexp tricks to force a regexp to be interpreted with a specific case?  I know that this is strictly speaking an iAnnotate question, but I am interested in possible `Pattern` regexp solutions.

Comment: Use inline modifie group, `(?-i:A)`, it will only match an uppercase `A`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thanks!  That works.  I never would have figured that out.  Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: OK, thanks for finding the duplicate @WiktorStribiżew.  I didn't think this would have been asked--I was sceptical that there was a solution and didn't know what to search for.